# How do I create a grid that has a semi-transparent background but solid children?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have something like this:

```
<Grid Background="Black" Opacitiy="0.5">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>...</Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Image Source="..." Opacity="1.0" Grid.Row="0"/>
  <TextBlock Text="..." Opacitiy="1.0" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Unfortunately the image and the text get rendered with 50% opacity as well.  What I want is a semi-transparent black background with 100% solid image and text children.

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a `Rectangle` as the first child of the grid, making sure that it spans all of the grid's rows and columns, with the opacity level you want:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>...</Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <Rectangle Fill="Black" Opacity="0.5" Grid.RowSpan="2" />

  <Image Source="..." Grid.Row="0"/>
  <TextBlock Text="..." Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

(I've removed the `Opacity` attribute from `Image` and `TextBlock` since it's not needed here.)

Comment: Ah... rowspan, okay.  I did try that, but without the rowspan.  Yes, I realize it wouldn't be needed, but I put Opacity on those to show what I had tried.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Or without the need for an additional UI element:

```
<Grid Background="#80000000" Opacitiy="0.5">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>...</Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Image Source="..." Opacity="1.0" Grid.Row="0"/>
  <TextBlock Text="..." Opacitiy="1.0" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Remembering that "#80000000" means Alpha (opacity) = "80", Red = "00", Green = "00", Blue = "00" and that these numbers are hexadecimal values

Comment: Thanks for nice solution! Actually you don't need to set Opacitiy="0.5".